# Gauge fixing conditions in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

Is there a limit to gauge fixing conditions we can impose in gravity ? I have seen two gauge fixing conditions. The DeDonder gauge $\partial_\mu g^{\mu\nu}$ and then in 3+1 formalism the gauge fixing condition $\nabla^2 t = 0$ is imposed where $t$ is the time coordinate. What if I imposed $\nabla^2 x_i = 0$ where $x_i$ is some spatial coordinate. Maybe a combination $\nabla^2(t^2+x^2) = 0$. How is the gauge fixing condition decided upon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of linearised GR, one of the main reasons for choosing our gauge fixing condition is just **sheer convenience**. If we're doing a metric perturbation of $g_{\mu \nu}  = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h _{\mu \nu} $, then our corresponding action that we get from perturbing our Ricci scalar is the Fierz-Pauli action which is second order in $h $ (since the first and zeroth orders vanish), the precise form of which you can look up in David Tong's notes on linearised gravity. 
$$ S_{FP} = \int d ^ 4 x \, L (h) .$$
Now, this yields a very difficult and verbose equation of motion to solve for $h_{\mu \nu } $ (which you can look up yourself in the same chapter), so to make things a bit easier we employ the fact that metric diffeomorphisms should leave our action unchanged, since they're just changes in coordinates. So, our action should be invariant under the change 
$$ h _{\mu \nu } \rightarrow h_{\mu \nu } + \partial _ \mu \xi _ \nu + \partial _\nu \xi _ \mu. $$ This freedom allows us 4 free parameters to fix, since $\xi$ has four components, and we choose constraining the four degrees of freedom via the de-Donder gauge because it **simplifies** our equation of motion in a vacuum to the simple 
$$ \Box  h _{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} \Box h \eta_{\mu \nu }  = 0 $$ Now, this is great because we can now set $\bar {h}_{ \mu \nu } = h _{\mu \nu } - \frac{1}{2} h \eta _{\mu \nu } $ which leaves us with $\Box \bar{ h}_{\mu \nu } = 0 $, which is just a wave equation which we can solve easily.

Comment: So you are saying that the gauge choice is a matter of pure convinience. You can choose any gauge fixing condition to suit your convinience ?

Comment: Provided that you are fixing the correct number of degrees of freedom and that the gauge is actually possible to fix to. In the example above, our gauge choice is motivated by coordinate transform invariance but there are other logical choices of gauge you can have.